# Exchange server 2016 HA

Tags: exchange, exchange-2016

I have an exchange server 2016 with mailbox server role already configured and we are trying to achieve high availability. 
In configuring the mailbox for H.A, how many mailbox server is required for on-prem HA config and for hybrid configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For high availability, at least two mailbox servers are needed.
Details see:
[Deploying high availability and site resilience](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638129%28v=exchg.160%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Microsoft Exchange Server 2016 uses the concept known as incremental deployment for both high availability and site resilience. You simply install two or more Exchange 2016 Mailbox servers as stand-alone servers, and then incrementally configure them and mailbox databases for high availability and site resilience, as needed.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the response. Will that suffice for about 1500 users?

Comment: It depends on your hardware  and the throughput of your daily mail. You can use Exchange Server Role Requirements Calculator 
 to estimate:https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Exchange-2013-Server-Role-f8a61780  In general, two mailbox servers will be enough.